# Mongo aggregation use $sort in conjunction with $geoNear

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework, gis, geonear

### Context :

I'm trying to build an architecture displaying POIs which can be at different know locations over time.

I have 2 collections,

pois

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: string
}
```

locations

```
  _id: ObjectId,
  point: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: Array<number>
  },
  poi: ObjectId // Reference to Poi
```

### Use-case :

So I'm trying to build a query which

- takes a center coordinate + radius in input
- and return the matching Pois within than radius
- with only their nearest Location
- sorted by distance

Ideally, having this output :

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(AE54232),
    name: 'Some poi',
    location: {
      _id: ObjectId(BFE5423),
      point: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [3, 50]
      },
      distance: 3
    }
  }
]
```

### Attempt

Reading carefully at the docs, I used this combination :

```
      // Keep only locations within radius,
      // output 'distance'
      // and sort by distance
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: nearCenter,
          key: 'point',
          distanceField: 'distance',
          maxDistance: nearRadius,
          spherical: true,
        },
      },
      // Keep only first (assumed 'nearest')
      // location of each poi
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$poi',
          location: {
            $first: '$$ROOT'
          }
        }
      },
      // Retrieve poi
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'pois',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'poi',
        },
      },
      // Flatten poi
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$poi',
        },
      },
      // Push poi at the root,
      // and put location inside 'location'
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$poi",
              { location: "$location" },
            ]
          },
        }
      },
```

So to sumup :

- `$geoNear`
- `$first(by poi)`
- `$lookup(poi)`
- `$unwind(poi)`
- `$replaceRoot(poi { location })`

### Trouble

I'm facing a strange behavior where the query basically works; excepts its not sorted by distance : the `poi`s with their `location` come in an erratic and non-determinist order !

I tried commenting every step one by one, and apparently this is the `$first` which is causing the "shuffle". Which is surprising since docs states :

[$geoNear](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)

> Outputs documents **in order** of nearest to farthest from a specified point.

[$first](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

> Returns the value that results from applying an expression to the first document in a group of documents. Only meaningful when documents **are in a defined order**.

### Fix attempts

My thought was `$first` expects an actual `$sort` and not an implicit `$geoNear` sorting; so I tried to intercalate a `$sort` in between like so :

```
      {
        $sort: {
          'distance': 1,
        },
      },
```

in between like so :

- `$geoNear`
- `$sort(distance)` <== HERE
- `$first(by poi)`
- `$lookup(poi)`
- `$unwind(poi)`
- `$replaceRoot(poi { location })`

But it gave me the exact same result !

---

The only thing that worked is adding a `$sort` at the very end like so

```
      {
        $sort: {
          'location.distance': 1,
        },
      },
```

- `$geoNear`
- `$first(by poi)`
- `$lookup(poi)`
- `$unwind(poi)`
- `$replaceRoot(poi { location })`
- `$sort(location.distance)` <== HERE

But I'm concerned it could have performance issues on large datasets

### Question

Is there any way to accomplish that logic

- filter $geoNear (keep distance)
- $group by referenced document, keep only 'nearest'

Without loosing $geoNear order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `poi` can have few locations then grouping them may change the order so the documents after the grouping are no longer sorted by `distance`. You can sort by `distance` after the grouping to solve it:

```
  {
        $geoNear: {
          near: nearCenter,
          key: 'point',
          distanceField: 'distance',
          maxDistance: nearRadius,
          spherical: true,
        },
      },
      // at this point you have all locations matching the criteria, sorted by `distance`
      // Keep only first (assumed 'nearest')
      // location of each poi
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$poi',
          location: {
            $first: '$$ROOT'
          }
        }
      },
      // at this point you have one location and its distance from `nearCenter per each `poi`. The grouping can change the order of documents 
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'pois',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'poi',
        },
      },
      // until here you retrieved the `poi` as `poi`
      {$sort: {distance: -1}}
      // now the `poi`s are sorted by distance
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {$first: "$poi"},
              { location: "$location" },
            ]
          },
        }
      }
      // Now the answer is formatted (no need to $unwind since you have only one item in the array)
```

Comment: Yeap thanks. That's what I discovered and I think I actually understood why. Making an answer, but accepting yours

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @nimrod serok's accepted answers

> If each poi can have few locations then grouping them may change the order so the documents after the grouping are no longer sorted by distance

I add an explaination on the "why" of this (too long for a comment).

### Statement

A `$geoNear` then `$group`(`$first`) on `poi` don't necessarily lead to `poi`s sorted by distance.

The reason is simple, but MongoDb doc is a bit unclear about it :

[`$first`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

> Returns the value that results from applying an expression to the first document in a group of documents. Only meaningful when documents are in a defined order.

This **doesn't mean** that "order of groups would be kept consistent"; this means that **the attribution of the `$first` of each group** will be consistent, only if it's sorted in input.

The key is in the "note" in the middle of the docs page :

> Although the $sort stage passes ordered documents as input to the $group and $setWindowFields stages, those stages are not guaranteed to maintain the sort order in their own output.

This basically means that order of input is respected for the `$first` resolution; but **the order of groups themselves is not consistent**.

### Example case

Say this is the result of $geoNear

```
- Location [id: 1, distance: 3, poi: 1]
- Location [id: 2, distance: 4, poi: 2]
- Location [id: 3, distance: 5, poi: 1]
- Location [id: 4, distance: 6, poi: 3]
```

`$group($first(poi))` guarantees that *location 1* will be kept and *location 3* discarded; but **does not guarantees** that *location 1* will be output before *location 2*.

The following result is then legit :

```
- Location [id: 2, distance: 4, poi: 2]
- Location [id: 1, distance: 3, poi: 1]
- Location [id: 4, distance: 6, poi: 3]
```

This is by nature.